# Does Microsoft Bot support Arabic language?

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, arabic

I want to check if Microsoft Bot can support the Arabic language.
Our customer needs to ask questions in Arabic and the bot to be able to chat with him using the Q&A knowledge base.

I do not have any code to share here, as I don't know whether it is possible or not.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to localization languages.

```
 Resources.Global.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

You may refer to this GitHub. Hope it may help you.

Comment: I think you forgot to include a link.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** it doesn't.

**Long answer:** it supports American English, Chinese, Dutch, French, French (Canada), German, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese (Brazil), Spanish (Spain, Mexico) and Turkish.

you can check this reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-language-support